# Way to use regex to do format translation with irregularities in data

Tags: regex, swift3

I have the following list of pairs (note generally a one to one mapping but some irregularities per the 4th item, where I have one irish word and two english:

```
béic yell,
can sing,
ceistigh question
fiafraigh inquire, ask,
```

I want to translate this as follows:

```
Synonym(irish: "béic", english: "yell"),
Synonym(irish: "can", english: "sing"),
Synonym(irish: "ceistigh", english: "question"),
Synonym(irish: "fiafraigh", english: "inquire, ask"),
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This one's pretty simple. The pattern you need is:

```
^(.+?) (.+),?$
```

If your string pairs are in an array, you can use a map operation to dump them into an array of `Synonym`s. If it's a single, `\n`-separated string, split it first on the line breaks before feeding it into the same map operation.

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4IPZQX/2)